# Add options to the FORMAT drop down in CKEditor?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

How can you add block formats to the Format drop down in CKEditor? There used to be an input in D7+WYSIWYG as to what was allowed.

No matter if I check or uncheck "Limit HTML to the following tags:", I cannot get the `cite` tag to show. Therefore, when using the blockquote button, I cannot highlight any text in it and change the format to `cite`.

How can I add the ability to change a piece of text to the `cite` tag within a `blockquote` or `p` tag?

Note: styles, html source buttons are out of the question.